# Excel spreadsheet 2010 locking down the ability to re-save document

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

My goal is to post an Excel spreadsheet that is searchable but lockdown. I'm able to lock down the cells.  What I'm not able to do is set up the document so it cannot be re-saved or reproduced. How can I set up an Excel spreadsheet that cannot be saved to a different file or moved by individuals?

Comment: why don't you just make it a read-only file? In this case the one with specific password can save and change it.

Answer (score 0):

You could password protect each sheet and check every box on the way down. 
See: http://blog.anypdf.net/wp-content/uploads/set-password-to-protect-excel.jpg

Or you could password protect the notebook as described here:
https://support.office.com/en-au/article/password-protected-the-workbook-7e365a4d-3e89-4616-84ca-1931257c1517

TL;DR--
File-->Save As-->(In Save As Menu) Tools-->General Options

It should provide you with a password to Open and a Password to Modify option.